# Could Not Load Main Class (Java)

Tags: java

Probably this is a repeated question, but I just couldn't find an answer to what I am looking for! I am trying to compile and run a java class in a Unix box.

I have the class as:

```
package tmp.test;

import org.jasypt.registry.AlgorithmRegistry;

class Algo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(AlgorithmRegistry.getAllPBEAlgorithms());

    }
}
```

The files are in the path `/tmp/test/`. Now I compile the class with the command:

```
javac -cp jasypt-1.9.3.jar Algo.java
```

The JAR file is in the same directory. It compiles just fine. But when I run the class file with the command:

```
java -cp jasypt-1.9.3.jar Algo
```

I get the error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Algo

I am executing all the commands from the path `/tmp/test/`.

I tried:

```
java -cp jasypt-1.9.3.jar tmp.test.Algo
```

and

```
java -cp jasypt-1.9.3.jar tmp/test/Algo
```

Both throw the same error.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. At first I thought it was the problem of the access thing. So I changed everything using `chmod` to 777. Everything seems to be fine. Can you please let me know what I am missing here?

Comment: Try tmp.test.Algo

Comment: @tibetiroka It tried that too, it still throws the same error.

Comment: Try making Algo a public class

Comment: @tibetiroka Its the same unfortunately! :(

Comment: @Sam - Do as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65735416/10819573) in a fresh folder. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: making Algo a public class is not helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am executing all the commands from the path `/tmp/test/`

That is the problem. You need to be one level above `tmp`, not somewhere inside. Then your command line

```
java -cp /path/to/jasypt-1.9.3.jar tmp.test.Algo
```

should work. If you insist in starting Java from the subdirectory inside your classpath, you can do this quite contrived thing:

```
 java -cp /path/to/jasypt-1.9.3.jar:../.. tmp.test.Algo
```

Comment: I tied the first command, it was throwing the same error. After I went to the outer directory. The path to the jasypt.jar was causing the problem. But the second command worked just nicely. Thanks.But in all honestly, what the heck does `../..` do here? A little explanation would be nice.

Comment: @Sam - "A little explanation would be nice." - Try reading this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: `..` means the parent directory (directly above where you are now). `../..` is the parent's parent directory. I think you are not just a programming newbie but also a UNIX or Windows command line newbie, are you not? Hang in there, as you learn more basics you will understand more.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use the switch `-d` to compile and then use the fully qualified name of the class to run it.

Compile the class as follows:

```
javac -d . -cp jasypt-1.9.3.jar Algo.java
```

The switch, `-d` specifies where to place generated class files and `.` stands for the current directory.

Run the class as follows:

```
java -cp jasypt-1.9.3.jar tmp.test.Algo
```

Comment: I tried it and it was throwing the same exception. But it got me pretty close. Thanks!